# Im trying to run applescript to take a variable from Filemaker (Client email address) to open all mail from this client

Tags: email, applescript, filemaker

Run from within Filemaker I want to run AppleScript to look through the mail inbox and have the ability to view the last 10  emails starting with the most recent. I have found script that will open specific sender emails but nothing that I can piece together to solve the issue.

tell application "Mail"
activate

```
repeat with receivedMessage in messages in inbox
    set theFilter to "colin@thebeadhouse.co.uk"
    set theSender to sender of receivedMessage
    set thisSender to (sender of receivedMessage as string)
    set theAddress to extract address from sender of receivedMessage
    set theEmail to sender of receivedMessage
    
    set receivedDate to date received of receivedMessage
    set messageContent to (get content of receivedMessage)
    if (((current date) - receivedDate) < 72 * hours) then
        
        if (extract address from sender of receivedMessage is equal to theFilter) then
            repeat with each_message in receivedMessage
                set the_subject to subject of each_message
                set the_date to date received of each_message
                set the_sender to sender of each_message
                set the_action to choose from list {"Open"} default items {} with prompt "Date: " & the_date & return & return & "Sender: " & theAddress & return & return & "Sender: " & the_sender & return & return & "Subject: " & the_subject & return & return & "Content: " & messageContent & return & return & "What do you want to do with this message?" & return with title "Messages within 24 hrs " without multiple selections allowed
                if the_action is false then return
                if item 1 of the_action is "Open" then open each_message
                if item 1 of the_action is "Mark as read" then set read status of each_message to true
                
                
                
            end repeat
        end if
    else
        
        return false
    end if
    
end repeat

return false
```

end tell

I'm almost there

Ive used some script from other postings to get the last time found messages  in this case 72 hours, i'm now trying to filter the selection down to specific email address which is the "if extract address from sender..." after the first if command. Im getting boolean error which i'm struggling to resolved at the moment

Comment: Post the scripts you have so far so we can fix them, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: P.S. I believe you can find the answer to the question in your title here: https://fmforums.com/topic/106820-calculated-applescript-syntax/?do=findComment&comment=482614&_rid=72594

Comment: Hi, Ive solved it, by extracting the address as a string- seems to work- now just got to figure  how to use in Filemaker with variables for the time and email address